# Power BI Multiple Data Sources - Cubes

Tags: olap, tableau-api, powerbi

is it possible to blend two OLAP cubes in Power BI? Tableau does not allow this, it is restricted to one OLAP cube as the primary, and the secondary source cannot be a cube.

Documentation I have read on Power BI does confirm multiple data sources are possible - of course - but does not seem to detail whether more than one source can be an OLAP cube.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in Power BI in a couple of ways:

1. Pull fields from 2 cubes into 2 tables, then add Relationships between them
2. Build a Query definition against 1 cube, but set the Table to "Hide in Report View".   Then build a Query from the 2nd cube, and add a Merge step to connect to the 1st Query.  Expand the Fields you need.

Option #1 is quicker to set up, #2 gives you more control over the join style.